# Sharing Type from One Class in Other Classes

Tags: vb.net, class, cookies, httpwebrequest, shared

I'm trying to make a class named *login class* that logs into a website and saves the cookies in a `cookiecontainer`. I then want to use the cookies saved in the `cookiecontainer` in other classes. I understand how to make a request and save the cookies in a `cookiecontainer`, however I do not know how to use the `cookiecontainer` in another class. Do I make the `cookiecontainer` a public shared type? How do I then access the cookies from this specific instance of the class?

**CODE:**

I am using code from http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-52-httpwebrequest-cookiecontainer/.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Class Login

    Public shared logincookie As CookieContainer

    Private Sub Login()

        Dim postData As String = "poststring"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("website"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a module to your project, make it public.

Create a public property in it.

```
Public Module Globals
    Public Property GlobalCookies As CookieContainer
End Module
```

This will allow you to share with other classes in the same solution.

You should be careful using globals as they increase complexity and can lead to bugs that are difficult to find.

Yes, this is functionally equivalent to the shared type on a class. Since VB has no shared class though I tend to use modules as they are actually what a shared class would be. You could have a class with all the properties shared and that is pretty much the same thing, but then you have to remember to not put non shared properties on that class.

I don't recommend putting shared state on classes that are ever instantiated, as the state is outside of the class's scope and that is not OO. Of course, shared functions are perfectly acceptable as that allows you to group similar behavior in one physical location.

Comment: Isn't this the same as declaring a type as shared?